# Shadow rendering issue when shadowCameraVisible = false

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

**Disclaimer:** *I am new to three.js and the world of 3D in general. I also didn't want to clutter the question with unnecessary code, so if there is some that would benefit, please let me know.*

I have a model with 3 spotlights, two from the sides that render shadow, and one from the front (same position as the camera) that shines light on the object.

When I was messing about with the side spotlights, both had `shadowCameraVisible` set to true for debugging purposes, and all was well.

As soon as I set `shadowCameraVisible` to false on **both** of them, the shadows no longer render correctly.
[image: Working shadows with shadowCameraVisible = true]
[image: Broken shadows with shadowCameraVisible = false]

The object in quesion contains two `MeshLambertMaterials` defined with side as `THREE.DoubleSide`, and the broken shadow resembles the object as it would be displayed if side was set to `THREE.FrontSide`.

Can anyone think of any reason why the shadow would be broken in this way? And why does the value of `shadowCameraVisible` change things?

**Update:**
I have now read that [the `material.side` parameter is ignored for shadows](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3544#issuecomment-19018897) and therefore this is what might be causing it. But this does still not explain why `material.side` appears to be not ignored when `shadowCameraVisible=true`!

**Update 2:**
Here's some code which might be relevant.

The 3D model has two faces which are defined as follows:

```
 var material1 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    shading: THREE.FlatShading,
    colors: THREE.FaceColors,
    vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors,
    blending: THREE.NormalBlending
 });
 var material2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    image: 'miscimage.jpg',
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    shading: THREE.FlatShading,
    colors: THREE.FaceColors,
    vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors,
    blending: THREE.NormalBlending
 });
 var materials = [materials1, materials2];
```

The `mesh` is defined as:

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
   geometry,
   new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials)
);
mesh.receiveShadow = true;
mesh.castShadow = true;
```

And the two spotlights:

```
var spotlight1 = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
spotlight1.position.set(-160, 300, -60);
spotlight1.shadowDarkness = 0.4;
spotlight1.intensity = 2;
spotlight1.castShadow = true;
scene.add(spotlight1);
var spotlight2 = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
spotlight2.position.set(160, 300, -60);
spotlight2.shadowDarkness = 0.4;
spotlight2.intensity = 2;
spotlight2.castShadow = true;
scene.add(spotlight2);
```

As mentioned, when one of the spotlights has `shadowCameraVisible=true`, then the shadows look like the first image, and when it is not set (i.e. to the default of `false`) you get the shadows in the second image. This makes it look as though `shadowCameraVisible=true` causes the shadow to honour the object's side setting of `THREE.DoubleSide` whereas having `shadowCameraVisible=false`, does not.

**Update 3:**
In fact, if I leave one of the cameras with `shadowCameraVisible=true`, and then go into three.js itself, and within the `THREE.CameraHelper` function and commented out all calls to `addLine`, the shadows work fine and you can't see the camera (of course). Further investigation is needed to find out just what within `THREE.CameraHelper` is allowing the shadows to work.

Comment: Can you edit [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uh7xf0sL/) and provide a live demo? Also paste relevant code in your post.

Comment: I have added some relevant code but haven't had the time to update the fiddle as of yet.

Comment: You may be onto somethhing. See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5232 and remove the texture.

Comment: Ah thanks, interesting. I'll give it a go tomorrow when I'm back in the office.